# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\DB\QueryBuilder'

Tags: php, oop

I have a problem with namespace. And I can't understand where I make a mistake.

This is the full error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\DB\QueryBuilder' not found in
>   D:\OSPanel\domains\mar\app\controllers\HomeController.php:21 Stack
>   trace: #0 D:\OSPanel\domains\mar\public\index.php(53):
>   App\controllers\HomeController->index(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   D:\OSPanel\domains\mar\app\controllers\HomeController.php on line 21

```
<?php

    namespace App\controllers;

    use App\DB\QueryBuilder;
    use League\Plates\Engine;

    class HomeController
    {
        private $templates;
            public function __construct()
            {

                $this->templates = new Engine('../app/views');
            }

        public function index($vars){

             $db = new QueryBuilder();
                $posts = $db->getAll('new_db');
                echo $this->templates->render('index.view', ['posts' => $posts]);

        }
    }
```

**This code in QueryBuilder**

```
<?php

namespace App\DB;

use Aura\SqlQuery\QueryFactory;
use PDO;


class QueryBuilder
{
    private $pdo;
    private $queryFactory;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=marlin",'root');
        $this->queryFactory = new QueryFactory('mysql');

    }

    public function getAll($table){
        $select = $this->queryFactory->newSelect('mysql');

        $select->cols(['*'])
                ->from($table);

        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($select->getStatement());

        $sth->execute($select->getBindValues());

        return $sth->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }


    public function getOne($id, $table)
    {
        $select = $this->queryFactory->newSelect();
        $select->cols([':id'])
                ->from($table)
        ->bindValues([
            ':id'=> $id
        ]);

        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($select->getStatement());

        $sth->execute($select->getBindValues());

        return $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function create($table, $value){
        $insert = $this->queryFactory->newInsert();

        $insert->into($table)
        ->cols([
            'title' => $value
        ]);

        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($insert->getStatement());

        $sth->execute($insert->getBindValues());
    }

    public function update($table, $id, $value){
        $update = $this->queryFactory->newUpdate();

        $update
            ->table($table)                  // update this table
            ->cols($value)
            ->where('id = :id')           // AND WHERE these conditions
            ->bindValues([                  // bind these values to the query
                ':id'   => $id
            ]);

            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($update->getStatement());

            $sth->execute($update->getBindValues());
    }

    public function delete($table, $id){
        $delete = $this->queryFactory->newDelete();

        $delete
            ->from($table)                   // FROM this table
            ->where('id = :id')           // AND WHERE these conditions
            ->bindValues([                  // bind these values to the query
                ':id' => $id,
            ]);



            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($delete->getStatement());

            $sth->execute($delete->getBindValues());

    }

}
```

Comment: Your autoloader config is probably busted. Post that and your directory structure.

Comment: Okay! I did it.